# Ionic 2 - Runtime error Cannot find module "."

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, webpack, ionic2

I have experienced this error when serving my Ionic 2 application to my localhost by using the command:

```
ionic serve
```

I am unsure where this error stems from. I have meticulously double checked all my imports for a broken path in my TypeScript files. I haven't found anything.

The only changes made between the application working and not working was adding a new interface for holding data for a Google maps Location.

However I don't see how this would be relevant and it has to be something else in the build process.

**app.modules.ts**

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import { Place } from '../model/place.model';
import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';

import { NewPlacePage } from '../pages/new-place/new-place';
import { PlacePage } from '../pages/place/place';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import { ActivePage } from '../pages/active/active';
import { PlacesService } from '../services/places.service';
import { ConnectivityService } from '../providers/connectivity-service';
import {AgmCoreModule }  from 'angular2-google-maps/core'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage,
    ActivePage,
    NewPlacePage,
    PlacePage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'hiddenforstackoverflow'
    })
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage,
    ActivePage,
    NewPlacePage,
    PlacePage
  ],
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}, ConnectivityService, PlacesService, Storage]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**places.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Place } from '../model/place.model';


@Injectable()
export class PlacesService {

    private places: Place[] = [];


    constructor(private storage: Storage) { }
    addPlace(place: Place) {
        this.places.push(place);

        console.log(this.places);
        this.storage.set('places', this.places);

    }

    getPlaces() {
        return this.storage.get('places')
            .then(
            (places) => {
                this.places = places == null ? [] : places;
                console.log(this.places);
                console.log(places);
                return this.places.slice();
            });

    }
}
```

**newplace.ts**

```
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { PlacesService } from '../../services/places.service';
import { Geofence, Geolocation, SMS } from 'ionic-native';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-new-place',
  templateUrl: 'new-place.html'
})


export class NewPlacePage {

  location: { lat: number, lng: number } = { lat: 0, lng: 0 };

  constructor(private placesService: PlacesService, private navCtrl: NavController) { }

  onLocateUser() {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()
      .then(
      (location) => {
        console.log('Location successful')
        this.location.lat = location.coords.latitude;
        this.location.lng = location.coords.longitude
      }
      )
  }
  onAddPlace(value: { title: string }) {
    console.log(value);
    this.placesService.addPlace({ title: value.title, location: this.location });
    this.navCtrl.pop();

  }

}
```

**place.model.ts**

```
export interface Place {
    title: string;
    location: {
        lat: number,
        lng: number
    }
}
```

**Ionic Versions**

```
 Ionic Framework: 2.2.0
    Ionic Native: ^2.4.1
    Ionic App Scripts: 1.2.5
    Angular Core: 2.4.8
    Angular Compiler CLI: 2.4.8
    Node: 7.7.4
    OS Platform: Windows 10
    Navigator Platform: Win32
    User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.8",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.0",
    "@types/google-maps": "^3.2.0",
    "angular2-google-maps": "^0.17.0",
    "ionic-angular": "2.2.0",
    "ionic-native": "^2.4.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.9",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^1.2.5",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "description": "ionic-boiler: An Ionic project"
}
```

Can anyone give advice on how to debug this further? Should I debug the **polyfils.ts** file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see 2 issues on your approach.

**Issue 1:** You have to remove this old module `"ionic-native": "^2.4.1",`.After that run `npm i`

**Issue 2:** You need to inject `Geolocation` inside the `providers` array (`app.module.ts`).You must do this with the latest ionic native (`"@ionic-native/core": "^3.4.4"`).

You can read more about it here: [**Ionic Native**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/).

Answer (score 33):

I know that the below solution it is not your case, but I have the same problem in Ionic 3.

The solution was reported on [Webpack issue discution](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4921)
by @killian2301.

Just remove all imports that have **/umd** at the final.

In my case, I changed:

`import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular/umd';`

To:

`import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';`

Comment: This error caused by VSCODE IDE, when move files and you choose 'YES' to do 'auto import'. All ionic-angular imports changed to ionic-angular/umd

Comment: None "ionic-angular/umd" in my code and the problem is still here.. any idea ?

Comment: This was a life saver. I have spent about 2 hours searching my code.

Answer (score 6):

This frequently occurs in Ionic 2+ , due to unusual auto import by IDE.

Change the code from

```
 import { TextInput } from 'ionic-angular/umd';
```

to

```
import { TextInput } from 'ionic-angular';
```

where ever it occurs with **package/umd**