# Cannot find module “.” when building prod release

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, production-environment, multiplatform

I am developing an Ionic4 application with Angular4 as core.

This time I don't need a help with programming (through might not be the best), but I need to create production package that can be used (at least) on the Google Play store.

Application runs fine on the phone run with:

`ionic cordova run android --device -lsc`

and simply in the browser with:

`ionic serve`

but when I do a production build either for browser or android platform with:

`ionic cordova run browser --release --prod`

or

`ionic cordova build android --release --prod`

I get:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "."
    at vendor.js:1
    at vendor.js:1
    at Object.<anonymous> (vendor.js:1)
    at i (vendor.js:1)
    at Object.557 (main.js:1)
    at i (vendor.js:1)
    at window.webpackJsonp (vendor.js:1)
    at main.js:1
```

One doesn't know much from this output. That's because implicit minify and uglify, which I can not turn off to see what is happening and as I said when running non-prod everything works fine.

I have read thread about `*-umd` imports causing this, but I don't use them.

So basically my question is how to fix this?

I have [pushed my project to the git](https://github.com/zapphyre/driveme) for anyone willing to help cause I am being really desperate and so much behind the schedule.

Any kind of help much appreciated!

EDIT: I should have told, you don't need any backend to get this error. It pops right after app loads.

Comment: hope this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43236971/ionic-2-runtime-error-cannot-find-module) would be helped.

Comment: well, accepted answer deals with /umd webpack issue and importing `Geolocation` as a provider in the app module which when I do, I get `circular dependencies (might be by using 'barrel' index.ts files.)` but I really don't import Geolocation anywhere else, so I still don't know

Comment: I did it wrong, but now I installed `@ionic-native/geolocation` and `cordova-plugin-geolocation` and properly imported `Geolocation` from `import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';` but it's the same :( 

repo updated

Comment: For anyone else having this issue, I was able to fix it with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50713430/ionic-3-build-in-prod-mode-cannot-find-module/50739472#50739472)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, I got this resolved however I cannot really tell the real cause.

I can give you some steps for making some analysis and find out what is going on through.

1. Install `ionic-app-scripts` globally and build project
   `ionic-app-scripts build`
2. cordova run browser

This should point you out some previously not seen errors.
Than, I found out that you can't have `NavController` injected at the root page because it doesn't exist yet. [reference.](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#navigating-from-the-root-component)

I also found out that I had some services injected twice.

Then, I suggest you to comment out all modules and providers and cativate it one-by-one with it's dependencies.

That way prod release has succeeded for me.